# Read 'MountedDevices' from Registry with Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, registry, mounted-volumes

The problem I have today is reading the information in 
the HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices registry. 
When I read using the terminal, thanks to the command "HIVEXSH" the information appears in clear. However, when I extract them using a Python3 script, they appear encoded, in the following format:

```
b'{\x00f\x00c\x00c\x009\x007\x008\x00b\x00c\x00c\x00-\x004\x005\x009\x001\x001\x001\x00e\x009\x0000-\x003\x008\x00d\x00d\x00e\x00a\x00a\x00d\x007\x00a\x004\x008\x008\x00c\x008\x00}\x00##x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x001\x000\x000}
```

within my script I tried to add a decoding function as follows:

```
            str=''''
            for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
                if m[i]<128:
                    str+=chr(m[i])
            print(str)
```

However, the output format is unreadable:

```
DI:DE'e
\???\USBSTOR#CdRom&Ven_hp&Prod_CDDVDW_GP70N&Rev_RR01#KXKHBUD5249_________&0#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
```

Here is my current code to read mounted devices :

```
def read_mountedDevices(sysreg):
    key = 'MountedDevices'
    try:
        mounted_devices = sysreg.open(key)
        for elt in mounted_devices.values():
            m = elt.value()

            str=''
            for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
                if m[i]<128:
                    str+=chr(m[i])
            print(str)

    except:
        print('no mounted devices found')
```

'''

The result I expect should be in the following format:
File mounted with its destination.

Comment: The value is the unique ID of a mountable device from [`IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/mountdev/ni-mountdev-ioctl_mountdev_query_unique_id). It's an arbitrary byte sequence, with no required format. For a volume handled by the volume manager, such as a partition on a disk, this ID can be based on the disk ID and partition offset. For removable media, it may be the UTF-16LE path of the underlying physical device such as "\??\USBSTOR#CdRom&Ven_<blah>" or "\??\SCSI#CdRom&Ven_<blah>".

Comment: If you want a printable string for this arbitrary byte sequence, without backslash escapes, you can translate it to hex digits (hexlify it) via `codecs.encode(m, 'hex').decode()`.

Comment: Thank's for all those explanations!

Comment: @alexjav83 were you able to resolve this? I want to get this mapping of drive letter and its Partition similar to Get-Partition